# Start Node.js server on Digital Ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, digital-ocean, droplet

I have created a Node.js Droplet on Digital Ocean.

I have connected to the server with FileZilla and uploaded all the Node.js files (index.js, package.json, etc.).

I am trying to start the server with `node index.js`. It says

```
App is running at http://localhost:3000 in development mode
  Press CTRL-C to stop
```

However, I am not able to see the website neither on the public IP address provided by Digital Ocean nor on `localhost:3000`.

How do I start the Node.js server correctly?

## Edit

I am setting up the server with this (content of `index.js`):

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
  console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});
```

Comment: Who knows... it's your application, how you specify the bind host is dependent on your code!  Only you can answer this.  Somewhere you want to bind to `::` or `0.0.0.0` (which is a pseudo address indicating you want to listen on all interfaces, in IPv6 or IPv4, respectively).  You'd also want to make sure that you don't have a firewall blocking `:3000`... but who knows how to help you there as you didn't even tell us what operating system you're running.

Comment: Alright, now that you've posted your code... your application is listening on all interfaces already, so this is going to come down to firewall config.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have just installed a Droplet with Node.js on Digital Ocean. The operating system in Digital Ocean is Ubuntu. My own operating system is OSX. It says I haven't created any firewalls on https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/firewalls.

Comment: Probably a firewall on your Ubuntu system, not the Digital Ocean cloud firewall.

Answer (score 4):

First you want to ensure everything is running fine by opening another terminal on the same machine and executing a curl.

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

After you have confirmed that is working, you will have to open the appropriate ports on the machine.

Let's see what ports are currently open by running the below command.

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

If port 3000 isn't listed, lets add it with the following command.

```
sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp
```

Verify port 3000 has been added by running `ufw status` again.

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877